# Regex : How to avoid matching a word in a string upon a condition

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have a problem with excluding some special condition. I already create example in this [LINK](http://regexr.com/3f17i).

If I have List of Sentence like this :

```
X-MAS TREE //it should be excluded because match my dictionary
BLA BLA TREE
XMAS TREE
X-MASTREE
X-TREE
X-MASTREE
```

And I have Dictionary that **X-MAS TREE** has synonyms: **XMAS TREE, X-MASTREE, X-TREE, TREE**.  And I need to change all the synonyms word into my Dictionary Word.

How to exclude **X-MAS TREE**?
Because all of those regex, will be replace with **X-MAS TREE**
If I search with keyword **TREE**, it will be infinite loop, because **X-MAS TREE** has **TREE**

I already tried many combination, but is not working:

```
\b(XMAS TREE|X\-MASTREE|X\-TREE|TREE|(?!X\-MAS TREE)\b
\b(XMAS TREE|X\-MASTREE|X\-TREE|(?!X\-MAS \s)TREE)\b
\b(XMAS TREE|X\-MASTREE|X\-TREE|((?!X\-MAS )|\w*)TREE)\b
\b(XMAS TREE|X\-MASTREE|X\-TREE|(?:(?!X\-MAS) )TREE)\b
```

**EDIT**

I need to use Boundaries (for some reason), because I create the regex in my code, with looping, and need to use it for another Dictionary, that why, for this case, I need special condition (without change the structure code, only edit the regex **TREE**)

Comment: Maybe listing all the unwanted cases as lookbehinds? [`\b(?<!XMAS)(?<!X\-MAS)(?<!X\-)\b(?<!XMAS\s)(?<!X\-MAS\s)TREE\b`](https://regex101.com/r/6pL1ul/1). Or do it in two steps: remove all `X-` in the blacklisted cases, and then replace `TREE` with with the required string.

Comment: the first three regex, I need it, only X-MAS TREE that need to be excluded. The other is correct.

Comment: You can try with :
[`/^([^X].+|X[^-].+|X-[^M].+|X-M[^A].+|X-MA[^S].+|X-MAS[^ ].+|X-MAS [^T].+|X-MAS T[^R].+|X-MAS TR[^E].+|X-MAS TRE[^E].+)/gm`](http://regexr.com/3f17o)

Comment: Then, try [`\b(?<!X-MAS\s)TREE\b`](https://regex101.com/r/6pL1ul/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah it works in the web.. Let me try in my Java Code first.. You can add your answer first, and let me try it before accept it. Because I use your regex in http://regexr.com/  and return error regex.

Comment: In regexr, only JS regex flavor is supported. You tagged your question with Java tag - Java regex supports lookbehinds. In Java, you need to declare the pattern as `String pat = "\\b(?<!X-MAS\\s)TREE\\b"`

Comment: @RadLexus yes I am. If I found "TREE" in my sentence, it will be changed to "X-MAS TREE" but if already contains "X-MAS TREE" it should not be recognized as synonym.

Comment: You know, in Java, you can even use a constrained width lookbehind, and if there can be 1 to several whitespaces between `X-MAS` and `TREE`, you may use `String pat = "\\b(?<!X-MAS\\s{1,10})TREE\\b";`

Comment: I never try that, thank you for your help, this is the answer, can you post it? and I can mark it as correct answer. Maybe you can add some explanation too. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match a whole word `TREE` that is not preceded with `X-MAS` and a whitespace, you may use a negative lookbehind `(?<!X-MAS\\s)` (or, to make sure the `X-MAS` is a whole word, `(?<!\\bX-MAS\\s)`):

```
String pat = "\\b(?<!X-MAS\\s)TREE\\b";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6pL1ul/2).

Also, if there can be more than 1 whitespace, say, from 1 up to 10, you may add a *limiting quantifier* `{1,10}` after `\s` to make sure more than 1 whitespace is still accounted for:

```
String pat = "\\b(?<!X-MAS\\s{1,10})TREE\\b";
```

Here, even if there are no or up to 10 whitespaces between `X-MAS` and `TREE`, the negative condition (the so-called [*constrained-width negative lookbehind*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#width)) will work.

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/8eajrH).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
^(?!X-MAS\s+TREE\s*)(?=.*TREE).*$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/50qzNc/2)

1. ^ asserts position at start of a line
2. Negative Lookahead `(?!X-MAS\s+TREE\s*)`
3. \s+ matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
4. Positive Lookahead `(?=.*TREE)` Assert that the Regex below matches .*
5. $ asserts position at the end of a line

To cover your comment's structure, you can try negative look behind

```
\b.*(?<!X-MAS )TREE\b
```

[Tried here](https://regex101.com/r/50qzNc/3)

Comment: I need to use my structure code, because for some reason, I cannot change my structure. This answer is work properly if I try my case without any future need.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what do you mean by your structure code ?

Comment: "\b(word|word|word|...|word)\b" I use this kind of structure

Comment: Why do you need \b ? Without that even your code works perfectly

Comment: I need that, because when I have some word like this CONDITIONAL, and I have dictionary that has synonym COND will be change to CD, it will be recognized and will be changed to CDITIONAL.